# Creating an alias for a constant pointer

Tags: c++

I wanted to know why the last statement is not valid ? I am a little confused with the information of the errors and would appreciate it if someone could clarify the error. I am aware the following code does nothing . I am just experimenting with an attempt to improve my concepts.I want to create an alias for pointer `p`

```
int a =12;
int * const p = &a; //p is a constant pointer to an int - This means it can change the contents of an int but the address pointed by p will remain constant and cannot change.
int *& const m = p; //m is a constant reference to a pointer of int type <---ERROR
```

These are the errors that I get

```
main.cpp:17:18: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int*&'
     int *& const m = p; 
                  ^
main.cpp:17:22: error: binding 'int* const' to reference of type 'int*&' discards qualifiers
     int *& const m = p;
```

Could anyone please explain what the two errors mean particularly the last one and if its possible to create an alias for pointer p.

Comment: Because it is a reference to a non-const pointer. When it was allowed, you could modify `p` through the reference, but `p` is const.

Comment: [Easy fix:](http://ideone.com/2juZzR) `const int * & m = p;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'int*&'
```

References cannot be re-bound after they are initialized. So there is no reason to put a const qualifier on a reference (not to be confused with a reference-to-const, which is a perfectly normal), since it cannot be changed anyway. That's the reason for the first error.

For the second error,

```
binding 'int* const' to reference of type 'int*&' discards qualifiers
```

`p` is a const pointer, but you are trying to bind a reference-to-non-const to it. That would allow you to change the const pointer through the reference, which cannot be allowed.

Here is the correct way to make a reference to `p`:

```
int * const& m = p;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
int a =12;
int* const p = &a;
int* const& m = p;
```

That defines `m` to be a reference to a `const` pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the two following lines:

```
int *const & const m = p; //m is a constant reference to a pointer of int type <---ERROR
int *const &  m = p; //m is a  reference to a pointer to a const int type <--- OK
```

Your comments give the answer. In your code, you define a constant reference to a pointer, that does not make sense. You need a reference to a pointer to const, which is my second line.